# How To Convert Apache Config To NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx

I am moving from an Apache to an NGINX environment and need to convert the following virtual server configuration to NGINX.

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/web
    ServerName myproject.dev
    ServerAlias myproject.dev

    <Directory /var/www/myproject/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What would be the "exact translation" of this to NGINX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.dev;
    root /var/www/myproject/web;
}
```

Start from here http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration.

Comment: What about all the stuff inside the directory tag, like AllowOverride, etc?

Comment: Nginx has nothing like `.htaccess` so `AllowOverride` is irrelevant. Other directives just allow access from anywhere which is default. You could look at http://nginx.org/r/allow if you want to restrict access.

Comment: When I use this config, the php files get downloaded rather than being executed.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help, just checkout and try it ;)

https://github.com/nhnc-nginx/apache2nginx

Comment: I just tried this and it seems to be terribly outdated with the latest nginx.